# React Router getHistory

Tags: reactjs, react-router

It is possible to get the list of browser history? For example, if I navigate as follows: `page1 -> page2 -> page1 -> page5`, I want to be able to get an array of `["page1", "page2", "page1", "page5"]` (so effectively `history.pop()` should give the URL of `goBack()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such API definition or implementation in either `History` object of browser or [`history` library](https://github.com/mjackson/history/blob/master/modules/createBrowserHistory.js) that used by `react-router`. It will cause some security problems (considering the situation of cross-domain).

However, you can listen for changes of location and store them manually. It won't bring security issues since the operations are all limited in a single domain:

```
history.listen((location, action) => {
    console.log(action, location.pathname, location.state);
    // you can store the result anywhere you like
    const prevUrls = window.sessionStorage.getItem('prevUrls') || [];
    prevUrls.push(location.pathname);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('prevUrls', prevUrls);
})
```

Then you can use `window.sessionStorage.getItem('prevUrls')` to get list of history.